# Why won't the keyPressed method be called?

Tags: java, user-interface, keylistener, keyevent

I'm making a fighting game in Java for a project and trying to get a picture to move and be repainted across the panel reacting to the keyboard (keyEvents).  I'm trying to accomplish this by having a switch in the keyPressed method, while adding the keyListener to the panel. I have been following an example in my Java book and the code I've written as nearly the same yet it just won't work.

What I'm really wondering is why it doesnt seem to react to keyEvents at all. The program compiles fine and all, yet nothing happens. I have no idea what is going wrong. It doesn't reach the breakpoint in the `keyPressed()` method if I make one, nor will it it do a `println()` if I put it in there. So the `keyPressed()` method doesnt react at all. I have also tested and made sure that the panel is focusable so I'm sure it has the keyboard focus.

```
public class MovePanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener {
    private ImageIcon currentImage, facingLeft, facingRight;
    private int position;
    private final int MOVEMENT;
    private GameFrame gameFrame;
    private URL lefturl, righturl;

    public MovePanel(GameFrame gameFrame) {
        // Taking in a gameFrame to be able to swap the active panel 
        // (not really relevant).
        this.gameFrame = gameFrame;

        // Adding the key listener here.
        addKeyListener(this);

        // These are just the Images I'm using to test. 
        // Trying to get it to swap from one to the other.
    lefturl = getClass().getResource("/Images/facingLeft.jpg");
    righturl = getClass().getResource("/Images/facingRight.jpg");

    facingLeft = new ImageIcon(lefturl);
    facingRight = new ImageIcon(righturl);

    currentImage = facingLeft;
    position = 50;
    MOVEMENT = 30;

    setBackground(Color.red);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,300));

        // Calling this method so that the panel will react 
        // to the keyboard without having to be clicked.
    setFocusable(true);
    }

    // This is just the paintComponent method which works fine to paint the image
    // when starting the game.
    public void paintComponent(Graphics page) {
    super.paintComponent(page);
    currentImage.paintIcon(this, page, position, 170);
    }

    // No matter what I try to do inside the keyPressed method
    // it doesnt seem to react at all.
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        // This switch is to make the method react accordingly to the keys pressed.
        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT: 

            // Here I'm changing the "active" image and the position 
            // by changing the position variable which is used 
            // to determine the x placement of the image.
            // This case is suppused to react if the left arrow key is pressed.
            currentImage = facingRight;
            position -= MOVEMENT;
            break; 
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT: 
            currentImage = facingRight;
            position += MOVEMENT;
            break; 

        // This case is to exit to the menu when escape is pressed.
        case KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE: 
            gameFrame.setMenuPanelActive();
            break; 
        }
        // After reacting to any of the proper keys pressed 
        // I'm trying to repaint which will use the
        // paintComponent method to paint the new image in its new position.
        repaint();
    }
    // I have empty definitions for the other 
    // implemented methods but won't be posting them.
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this doesn't work? Why `keyPressed()` method won't react?

Comment: Probably the frame is catching the event... Are you sure the panel is on focus? Put such a listener also on the frame and see if it is called:)

Comment: Your code seems to work fine for me. Are you sure that no other component has the focus?

Comment: How would I check if that is the case? And how could the frame do that when I'm adding the listener to the panel? Really at a loss, even my professor didnt see why this won't work :(

Comment: I used if (this.isFocusable() == true) 
 setBackground(Color.black); to see if It was focusable, I have also used this.requestFocus(); in the constructor to see if that was the problem, though I cant be sure. Really not used to the commenting system here, I keep commenting when trying to put a new line :P I will try and add a listener to the frame.

Comment: I tried using if (gameFrame.isFocusOwner() == true) {
   System.out.println("ppifjlos"); } since Eclipse said hasFocus() was obsolete. Trying to test if the frame has focus but it seems it doesnt. Also tried to do it on the panel and it doesnt do anything there either so doesnt seem like it has focus.

Comment: @Clearout: i have edited my answer, kindly look at it.

Comment: Well thanks for trying all of you, gonna go smash my head against a brick a bit and see if something pops out :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont see the code like below

you should call the below line where u create the instance of  **MovePanel**

```
 MovePanel.requestFocus();      // Give the panel focus.



public class demo extends JFrame 
{
    MovePanel  panel;

    public demo () 
    {
        panel= new MovingTextPanel();
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout())
        this.setTitle("Demo");
        this.pack();
        panel.requestFocus();      // Give the panel focus.
    }
}
```

In your MovePanel  add setFocusable to true

```
 public MovePanel(GameFrame gameFrame) {

        this.setFocusable(true);   // Allow this panel to get focus.
        // Adding the key listener here.
        addKeyListener(this);
```

**Some more traces**

```
- Characters (a, A, #, ...) - handled in the keyTyped() listener.
- Virtual keys (arrow keys, function keys, etc) - handled with keyPressed() listener.
- Modifier keys (shift, alt, control, ...) - Usually their status (up/down) is tested by calls in one of the other listeners, rather than in keyPressed().

  public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
  }
  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
   System.out.println(e.toString());
  }
  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
  }
```

Comment: requestFocusInWindow() is more recommended than requestFocus() :)

Comment: I tried adding the movePanel.requestFocus(); where I created the MovePanel but it doesnt do anything, and it still wont pass the check Ive made in the constructor of MovePanel using this.isFocusOwner(). I don't know why it wont focus, since the isFocusable() method yields true :(

Comment: @Suresh S I added the traces to the listeners, nothing happened. Amazing how a scrub programmer like me can mess things up :P

Comment: @Suresh-S I added the listener to the frame and it seems it is indeed the one stealing the focus somehow since the traces react there. Does this help anything?

Comment: @Clearout: if there is a listener for frame , comment it out and try.

Comment: @Suresh-S It's working, oh my god, ITS WORKING YES! Thank you so much!!! (The error was a case in the switch which tried to use the frame to change window that messed everything up). So happy now!